# Django Doesn't Serve STATIC_ROOT in DEBUG

Tags: python, django, static

I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 1.10 to run a development server:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

In my `settings.py` I have:

```
DEBUG       = True
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL  = '/static/'
```

And an `app` directory, with a `static` subdirectory for its static files:

```
proj/
    proj/
        ...
    app/
        static/
            a.txt
        ...
    static/
        b.txt
```

Pretty standard.

However: **Django doesn't serve the `STATIC_ROOT` when `DEBUG = True`**. It returns `app/static/a.txt` for `/static/a.txt` alright, but not `static/b.txt` for `/static/b.txt`.

Changing `settings.py` to read:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Works - but then I have to comment out `STATIC_ROOT` (otherwise Django complains it can't be in `STATICFILES_DIRS`).

Now, I can't just "use a different external static directory", e.g. `static2`, because I'm using `django-sass-processor`, which compiles `.sass` files into `.css` files, and puts these `.css` files in the `STATIC_ROOT` (which, as I've said, is inaccessible).

Things I've tried:

1. Settings up NGINX to serve that directory (like in a production environment). Works, but there just has to be another way.
2. Configuring `django-sass-processor` to write the `.css` files into said "different external static directory", e.g. `static2`, and including it in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Again, works, but it just *can't* be that complicated!
3. Manually adding static files URLs in `urls.py`:

   ```
   if settings.DEBUG:
       urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```

   This one was quite a trip, so I thought I'd share it to save other people the trouble: it turns out that Django does that *anyway*, and actually *overwrites* my URLs - but it includes, as I've said, only my apps' static directories and those in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

   I even changed `DEBUG` to `False` and removed the `if` - but that didn't work as well, because then the `django.conf.urls.static.static` function *actually returns an empty list*. So, I implemented it myself using `django.views.static.serve`, and it finally worked, but again - it doesn't make sense I have to turn off debugging and manually implement serving static file.

**Update**

4. If you're working with `django-sass-processor` and running into similar problems, they've actually provided a solution I just noticed in their documentation: a special static finder you can add in your `settings.py` like so:

   ```
   STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
       'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
   ]
   ```

   (The first two are Django's default finders, so when you override this configuration you should include them manually).

   But even now, for anything *other* than `.css` files, the `STATIC_ROOT` is actually the only static directory that is inaccessible via `/static/`, which I find pretty odd. So, I'd still like to solve (or at least understand...) it.

Comment: I've been working with django for almost ten years now. I always have trouble setting up static files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a simple issue of priority. I tried added `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to urlpatterns, and I removed `django.contrib.staticfiles` from INSTALLED_APPS. This way, files in `STATIC_ROOT` are accessible, but not files in `myapp/static`. If I add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, the opposite happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At first glance it seems very strange that Django doesn't serve files from `STATIC_ROOT`, but it makes sense when you consider the workflow Django intends for static files. Django expects that you bundle static files alongside apps and you save project-level static files in a separate directory that is checked into version control. Then, when you run `manage.py collectstatic` the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` are used to gather up all the files into a single directory (which should *not* be in version control) so they can be deployed to AWS S3 or whatever.

So the staticfiles finders have two jobs:

1. find a file via path, used for DEBUG mode static file serving
2. list all of the available files, used for collectstatic

If you were able to include `STATIC_ROOT` in your `STATICFILES_DIRS` then the collectstatic command would probably get stuck in a loop. Also, the Django developers don't intend for you to save files in `STATIC_ROOT` since it shouldn't be checked into version control.

However, there's times when you actually do want to serve files from `STATIC_ROOT`. In my case, I have a Celery task that creates thumbnails of uploaded images and saves them to the static files storage. In production that ends up saving on AWS S3 where it can be served.

So, if you have a valid use case for serving files from `STATIC_ROOT` just define your own file finder and add it's path to `STATICFILES_FINDERS`:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.finders import BaseFinder
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

class StaticRootFinder(BaseFinder):
    """
    For debug mode only. Serves files from STATIC_ROOT.
    """
    def find(self, path, all=False):
        full_path = staticfiles_storage.path(path)
        if staticfiles_storage.exists(full_path):
            return [full_path] if all else full_path
        return []

    def list(self, ignore_patterns):
        return iter(())
```

Comment: This exactly the answer I was looking for because it explains the reason for NOT serving the files from STATIC_ROOT when in debug a definite +1 from me. I was coming to same conclusion myself and just needed to see someone else say the same thing!